# Extract string literals that are not internationalized?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I'm looking for a way to extract all string literals from an Xcode project which are not being internationalized using the NSLocalizedString() macro, in cased I missed any. Is there is simple way of doing this?

Comment: By *not being internationalized* do you mean the ones that you forgot to use NSLocalizedString() on or the ones that you don't have in your translation tables?

Comment: The ones where I forgot to use NSLocalizedString()

Comment: Hate to be bearer of bad news, but you will have to do this manually. There is no way for any automatic tool to distinguish where you forgot to use NSLocalizedString and where you really wanted to use literal (like notification names etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Try the genstrings tool. It is run from the command line:

```
genstrings -o en.lproj *.m
```

Comment: That will only pick up the ones where I'm using NSLocalizedString(), unless I'm missing something?

Comment: It would seem that way ... now I have two problems

Comment: +1 for Two Problems! :-) Time to write your own tool! I would write it in Python, and use PyQT to do a really quick UI, but they you don't necessarily know python... So maybe a tiny Cocoa or AppleScript hack?